# JQuery Validation Engine : Validate with Ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to check if a particular record already exists in database before adding a new record.

ajax Call

```
"ajaxRecordExistsCall": {
                    "url": "Controller?action=GET_LIST",
                    "extraDataDynamic": ['#id'],
                    "alertText": "* Record already exists",
                    "alertTextOk": "good to go!",
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                }
```

The resulting HTTP request header looks like this

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz/Controller?action=GET_LIST&fieldId=Edit-Id&fieldValue=someValue&_=1430828274372
```

where as I want a HTTP request header to like this, in order to make it work.

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz/Controller?action=GET_LIST&id=someValue
```

why it is appending `fieldId` & `fieldValue` to `HTTP request header`?

From Controller,corresponding response is returned as JSON string.

```
jsonArray = "{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + jsonArray + "}";
```

Problem: jquery continously display following`"alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"`

where as, it should display `"alertText": "* Record already exists",` if the record exists.

what kind of response ajaxCall requires in order to display proper error alert?

Where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The response is Boolean true or false
["Edit-Id",false] will display the alertText
["Edit-Id",true] will display the alertTextOK